# How to configure auto-show buttons from bootstrap-markdown?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, browser

I am using the wonderful editor [bootstrap-markdown](http://toopay.github.io/bootstrap-markdown/) But they show a list of edit buttons shown below [image: Edit Buttons]

I want to Change the default alert button which shows when u click on 'Add Url' Tag.

Comment: Read your question again... not sure what you mean by "whown" and I didn't edit because I don't know what to edit it to. I also didn't understand the question very well, you might need to rephrase it a little bit to help us help you better. What do you mean when you say you want to change the alert box, you mean to something else? different design? Try to be a bit more specific if you can please.

Comment: apologies. its 'shown'

Comment: I just figured out that "whown" means "shown" honest mistake

Comment: edited the question to make it more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit this (depending on what you want to do) in line `770` of the `bootstrap-markdown.js` file.

You will find this block of code there:

```
name: 'groupLink',
data: [{
  name: 'cmdUrl',
  title: 'URL/Link',
  icon: 'icon icon-globe',
  callback: function(e){
    // Give [] surround the selection and prepend the link
    var chunk, cursor, selected = e.getSelection(), content = e.getContent(), link

    if (selected.length == 0) {
      // Give extra word
      chunk = 'enter link description here'
    } else {
      chunk = selected.text
    }

    link = prompt('Insert Hyperlink','http://')
```

Let us know if this information was helpful.